# Frame with mutiple jpanel

Tags: java, swing

Sorry, I am new here and im new with java and swing. I am trying to build a simple application . I have search throughout the internet but  I still don't understand.

I have just started with Java swing and I am stuck with layout manager . I want to create a something like this, but it will only display the "test 2" JButton and ignore all the other component

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setsize(200,200);
frame.setlayout(new Borderlayout());
frame.add(new JTextField(10), borderlayout.page_start);
frame.add(new JButton("test 2"), borderlayout.page_start);
frame.setvisible(true);
```

The layout is something like this

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    /* Hi, Welcome to stack overflow.
     * The reason why you only see the button 2 is because it is overlapping one another.
     * I would suggest you to look through the layoutManager https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html and really get your hands dirty
     * There are many ways of getting your desired result, you can do it with GridBagLayout but i would suggest you create JPanel and make it as a container
     * The reason why you only see the button 2 is because it is overlapping one another 
     */

public static void main(String[] args){

    //Variable 
    JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
    JButton btn = new JButton("Enter");
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea(50,50);

    //-- Main frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
    //IF you need a specific size , you can set your preferred size to your jframe
    //otherwise , you can just use frame.pack() at the end of the code 
    //frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //-- Top Container
    JPanel topContainer = new JPanel();
    topContainer.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    topContainer.add(field);
    topContainer.add(btn);

    // Now add your container to your main frame 
    frame.add(topContainer,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    frame.add(area,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So which means I can include more than one container ?

Comment: Yes you are able to add as much container as you want . I would suggest to do alot of practice on LayoutManager, once you master this, it will be easier in the future :). cheers

Comment: Good edit. `IF you need a specific size..` then the app. will likely require a specific size on the **content area** of the frame, or some specific component within it (e.g. a game play area). Iv'e never seen a single instance that justified having the exact same **frame size** across platforms (which have different sizes of 'window decorations'). And a tip: Add @LTprogrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.